# How to use tokenized sentence as input for Spacy's PoS tagger?

Tags: nlp, nltk, spacy

Spacy's pos tagger is really convenient, it can directly tag on raw sentence.

```
import spacy  
sp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')  
sen = sp(u"I am eating")
```

But I'm using tokenizer from `nltk`. So how to use a tokenized sentence like 
`['I', 'am', 'eating']` rather than 'I am eating' for the Spacy's tagger?

BTW, where can I found detailed Spacy documentation?
I can only find an overview on the [official website](https://spacy.io/api/annotation#pos-tagging)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There's two options:

1. You write a wrapper around the `nltk` tokenizer and use it to convert text to spaCy's `Doc` format.  Then overwrite `nlp.tokenizer` with that new custom function. More info here: https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features#custom-tokenizer.
2. Generate a `Doc` directly from a list of strings, like so:

   > doc = Doc(nlp.vocab, words=[u"I", u"am", u"eating", u"."],
   >   spaces=[True, True, False, False])

   Defining the `spaces` is optional - if you leave it out, each word will be followed by a space by default. This matters when using e.g. the `doc.text` afterwards. More information here: https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features#own-annotations

[edit]: note that `nlp` and `doc` are sort of 'standard' variable names in spaCy, they correspond to the variables `sp` and `sen` respectively in your code