# An efficient way to 'sentencize' Spacy docs and then apply POS tags

Tags: python, nlp, tokenize, spacy

I'm looking to use the 'sentencizer' as I want to create some custom POS groupings that need to follow a rule in each individual sentence, thus I can't rely on the standard POS tagging as a first step.

I can think of a way to run the POS tagger first, get the idx of each tag, group out each sentence, and then just get the POS' I want... but I'm lazy and hoping there's something more elegant.

Is there anything I missed from the docs?

**Research and Methods**
Here's one alternative... [stackoverflow.com/questions/56437945/how-to-use-tokenized-sentence-as-input-for-spacys-pos-tagger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56437945/how-to-use-tokenized-sentence-as-input-for-spacys-pos-tagger)

Example that obviously won't work as the nlp object needs a str:

```
import spacy; from spacy.lang.en import English; nlp = English()
nlp.add_pipe(nlp.create_pipe('sentencizer'))

def token_pos_pair(token):
    lst = []
    doc = nlp(token)
    lst.append([sent for sent in doc.sents]) 
    print(lst)
    token = [(sent, sent.pos_) for sent in nlp(lst)]

doc = 'Designing of both simple and complicated Campaign assets like Email, Forms, and Landing pages. Programers program programs with programming languages'

token = token_pos_pair(doc)
```

> TypeError: Argument 'string' has incorrect type (expected str, got
>   list)

Comment: Is from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize useful for you

Comment: Can you add an example with the expected input and output?